# Como faço pra printar a saída em linhas diferentes nesse código?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Divisores I#

def divisores(num):
    for i in range(1, num//2+1):
        if num % i == 0: 
            yield i
    yield num

num = int(input())
print(list(divisores(num)))
```

A resposta está saindo na mesma linha, queria q elas ficassem uma abaixo da outra, mas não consigo.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é `for x in lista: print(x)`.

Comment: Guilherme, dá uma [pesquisada no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bpython-3.x%5D+print+linha) pois já tem bastante conteúdo sobre isso. ;)

Comment: Complicando: `print('\n'.join([str(i) for i in list(divisores(num))]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você resolver esta questão você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def divisores(n):
    for i in range(1, (n // 2) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i


num = int(input())
for j in divisores(num):
    print(j)
```

Segundo a documentação **[yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)** é uma expressão de rendimento que serve como função geradora e, dessa forma, só pode ser usada no corpo de funções.

Quando uma função geradora é chamada, é retornado um `iterator` conhecido como gerador. Desse modo o gerador controla a execução da função geradora. Nesse momento é executado a primeira expressão de rendimento sendo em seguida, sua atividade é suspensa, retornando dessa forma o valor da [expression list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-expression-list). Em seguida o processo é refeito até ser concluída toda as operações.

**Observação**

Este código serve para calcular os **DIVISORES PRÓPRIOS** de um número.

Agora, se você deseja calcular os **DIVISORES NATURAIS** de um número, você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def divisores(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i


num = int(input())
for j in divisores(num):
    print(j)
```